# Is NGARCH a ARCH or GARCH-Model?

Tags: r, garch

I have got a question, that I cannot solve for myself.

I´m modeling with R and plan to compare diffrent GARCH-Models (GARCH only, no ARCH) in modeling and forecasting the standarddeviation of several time series.

My current overview is SGARCH, NGARCH, EGARCH, GJRGARCH and TGARCH. The plan is to compare two symmetric GARCH-Models and three asymmetric GARCH-Models.

Everything seems fine, but I´m very confused about the NGARCH Model. Is it a ARCH-Model or belongs the NGARCH to the real GARCH Family and the n stands for nonlinear (=symmetric)?

Comment: Could you give us something more than just an acronym? What are the equations behind NGARCH?

Comment: I would but I don´t know what you mean by that. That shows my problem as well. I do not know what the specifications or equations of NGARCH are.

Comment: If you are using `rugach`, check out pages 9-10 of its [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rugarch/vignettes/Introduction_to_the_rugarch_package.pdf). The document seems to show NGARCH is a GARCH model in the sense of including past conditional variances on the right hand side of the equation for the current conditional variance.

Comment: Yes, I want to use NGARCH of the rugarch package.

Comment: What I didn´t get yet... What is the difference between standard GARCH and NGARCH?

Comment: If you write down the equations constituting each model, this should become obvious. Have you tried that?